# CSS in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, css, qt

I can't find anything on this topic, is it possible to use CSS files in Qt or do I have to use setStyleSheet on every element I want to style?

I can't say its very maintainable if I have to write all the styles in quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-stylesheet` to specify a stylesheet on the command line.  In addition, you could load your .qss file from a file or a resource and then call [setStylesheet](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop) on your QApplication instance.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get the external file loaded in QApplication. I tried a.setStyleSheet(":<prefix>/<alias>");

Comment: Once you've added the file as a resource you need to open the resource and read it into a string. You can start the process with: `QFile stylesheet(":<prefix>/<alias")` and then reading in the text. Perhaps:  `stylesheet.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); QTextStream ts(&stylesheet); a.setStyleSheet(ts.readAll());`