# How to use CSS in Qt framework

Tags: c++, css, qt

Is it possible to use CSS(style sheet) in Qt creator? The code was written in c++ and Qt style sheets don't seem to be the best way to remove border spaces between layouts.
If there is any way to use css for removing border spaces, which header file i have to add in my code?

I have one vertical layout, which contains one horizontal layout and qlabel. When i try to resize my widget and do screenshot, there is some space between layouts. I think,that it is because of borders.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: See if [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992111/css-in-qt-creator) is helpful.

Comment: @ThePhantomGamer it was similar to my problem, but didn't understand what should i do...If you can explain it in detail, i'll be very thankful

Comment: here is what I found.

* [how to set a stylesheet for an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810729/qt-setstylesheet-from-a-resource-qss-file)

* [more detailed guide for above](http://qtacademy.blogspot.com/2015/12/external-qss-file.html)

* [official docs for 'qss' stylesheets](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html)

Unfortunately, I have never worked with Qt so I can't provide specific help.